# Where do variables outside of a square root go?

Tags: arithmetic

This is a formatting question. Example, $\sqrt{4}x^2 \text{ or } x^2\sqrt{4}$. Which is less ambiguous? Is there a style guideline for things like this?

Comment: Clearly one should write $2x^2$.

Comment: They go to heaven!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Particularly when writing by hand, I prefer $x^2\sqrt 4$.  It avoids the worry that the top bar of the square root sign might extend over the $x^2$ and make you think it is inside.  Even when typeset, it keeps people from worrying that you forgot some braces and the $x^2$ belongs inside.

Comment: I always write something like $\large\tt\mbox{\,\sqrt{4\,}\,}$ when I use $\large\tt LaTeX$. Indeed, I define another one which is based in the above scheme.

Comment: $\large\tt\mbox{\newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{#2\,}\,}}$

Answer (score 6):

Also, this is a good occasion to use a TeX "\cdot", as in $\sqrt{4}\cdot x$. It is true that writing "$x^2\,\sqrt{4}$" disambiguates, but to me it looks very strange, definitely stranger than having the "\cdot" inserted. I've gotten into the habit of using more "cdots" in handwritten things since "discovering" the TeX use. Tastes vary...

Comment: I also prefer the numerical part on the left. Another option is to ["close" the root](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/29834/31104). (+1)

Answer (score 1):

The numerical coefficient is usually put before the variable.  I would go for $(\sqrt{4})x^2$.